# How to configure org-plus-contrib?

Tags: org-mode

I was trying to use `org-drill`, so I installed `org-plus-contrib`. That caused me a lot of problems, which I finally resolved by finding out that if emacs loads org related stuff, the installation doesn't work properly. So I deleted my `emacs.d` and started over and managed to install it properly and `org-drill` was working fine. At this point my `init.el` file only consisted of melpa and org elpa references,

```
(package-initialize)

;; Add the melpa package repository
;; Remember to always use HTTPS
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
;; org-elpa
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

not my full configuration. Later when I added my previous configuration, org-drill stopped working. Maybe something in my configuration is causing problems, but I can't figure out what.

This is my `init.el` file:

```
(package-initialize)

;; Add the melpa package repository
;; Remember to always use HTTPS
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
;; org-elpa
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)

;; Remove the splash screen
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; Remove the tool bar
(customize-set-variable 'tool-bar-mode nil)

;; Remove the menu bar
;;(customize-set-variable 'menu-bar-mode nil)

;; Remove scroll bar
(customize-set-variable 'scroll-bar-mode nil)

;; smoother scrolling
(setq redisplay-dont-pause t
      scroll-margin 1
      scroll-step 1
      scroll-conservatively 10000
      scroll-preserve-screen-position 1)

;; load the theme
(load-theme 'dracula t)

;; remap marker moving keys vim-style
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'backward-char) ; was indent-new-comment-line
(global-set-key (kbd "M-;") 'forward-char)  ; was downcase-word
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k") 'previous-line) ; was tab-to-tab-stop
(global-set-key (kbd "M-l") 'next-line)     ; was kill-sentence

;; org-mode
;; ========

;; Add org-directory
(setq org-directory "~/org/")

;; Add my org files folder
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/"))

;; open project.org file
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p")
        (lambda()
          (interactive)
          (find-file "~/org/projects.org")))

;; ==========
;; org-capture

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)

;; set org-capture file
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "~/org/capture.org"))

;; ====================
;; insert date and time

(defvar current-date-time-format "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
  "Format of date to insert with `insert-current-date-time' func
See help of `format-time-string' for possible replacements")

(defvar current-time-format "%a %H:%M:%S"
  "Format of date to insert with `insert-current-time' func.
Note the weekly scope of the command's precision.")

(defun insert-current-date-time ()
  "insert the current date and time into current buffer.
Uses `current-date-time-format' for the formatting the date/time."
       (interactive)
       (insert (format-time-string current-date-time-format (current-time))))

(defun insert-current-time ()
  "insert the current time (1-week scope) into the current buffer."
       (interactive)
       (insert (format-time-string current-time-format (current-time))))

(global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" 'insert-current-date-time)
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-t" 'insert-current-time)

;; useful function in the renaming pdf file workflow
;; =================================================

(defun close-and-kill-next-pane ()
  "If there are multiple windows, then close the other pane and kill the buffer in it also"
  (interactive)
  (other-window 1)
  (kill-this-buffer)
;;  (if (not (one-window-p))
;;      (delete-window))
  (other-window 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") 'close-and-kill-next-pane)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-modules
   (quote
    (org-bbdb org-bibtex org-docview org-gnus org-info org-irc org-mhe org-rmail org-w3m org-drill)))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (org-plus-contrib dracula-theme)))
 '(scroll-bar-mode nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Now `org-drill` no longer works. I've tried `M-x find-library RET org-drill` and it can find the file, but emacs doesn't load it. Org-mode has also stopped working properly. I'm using org version 9.0.2 and emacs 25.1.

Comment: Since `org-drill` works when you use a minimal `init` file, the problem is somewhere in the rest of your `init`.  The standard steps to take in this situation are to bisect your init file recursively by commenting out successive halves until you isolate the code that is causing `org-drill` to malfunction.

Comment: @Dan Ok so I started incrementally adding changes to my setup from bare emacs. I created the init.el file added only the melpa and org elpa parts. I restarted emacs and installed org-plus-contrib, then selected drill in `M-x customize-variable RET org-modules`. This got org-drill to work. Then I install dracula-theme, and the old problem came back. How could dracula-theme cause such a problem? I got this error when I tried to open emacs again `File mode specification error: (void-function org-drill-add-cloze-fontification)`.

Comment: No idea what's causing it.  You'll have to dig into the source code, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dan I have not much experience with Emacs architecture, or really any other extensible editor architecture, but should one package/library/module be able to affect another? Are they not isolated?

Comment: @Dan I checked out the rest of my configuration and no problems surfaced. The error must have originated from `dracula-theme`, which I never would have guessed.

Comment: @Dan Also did you mean the source code of `dracula-theme` or `org-drill` or both?

Comment: check your .emacs.d/elpa do you have org and org-plus-contrib directories after calling Dracula-theme, where there weren't before?  I think the solution involves preceding your call to 'org-capture with `with-eval-after-load-org`